# When can you bring the partial differentiate outside the integral?

Tags: probability, integration

I want to know why this equality is truth, considering that $f_{\theta}(x)$ is a density function.
$$
\int_{\chi} \frac{\partial^{2} f_{\theta}(x)}{\partial \theta \partial\theta^{T}} \,dx = \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial\theta\partial\theta^{T}} \int_{\chi}f_{\theta}(x)\,dx
$$
Is it because $f_{\theta}(x)$ is continuous? Which theorem do you use?

Thank you.

Comment: take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)